# Sun path formula

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, rotations, mathematical-astronomy

How can I calculate the unit vector to the sun for specific time relative to observer position, given with lat:lon coordinates, considering Y+ axis directed to North, X+ axis directed to East and Z+ directed as radius vector to observer position from center of the Earth?

**UPDATE**: Answering to  hardmath's comment, the Earth may be considered as ideal sphere, Earth's orbit may be considered as ideal circle and Earth's axis tilt may be considered as $\mathcal E = 23.4°$.

P.S.: Sorry for bad English.

Comment: This depends on time in a very complicated way.  The obvious elements of chronological variation are the Earth's rotation and the Earth's tilted orbit around the Sun.  Additional factors that would have to be considered for inclusion in your model are the elliptical eccentricity of Earth's orbit, the precession of the Earth's tilt, tidal effects of the Moon's orbit around the Earth.  In short the answer could well be contingent on a lot of physical astronomy that is not provided in your Question.

Comment: There was a time when I did this from scratch on paper. It's ghastly, but you can get through (or look it up anywhere on the net if you just want the result). What I did: fix a coordinate frame to the earth (but not rotating). Write the coordinates of the rotated (here time comes in) point at that latitude and longitude. Get the local frame at that point by a few cross products. Express the unit vector of the sun direction in external coordinates in the local coordinates by computing 3 dot products. That's without precession and orbit eccentricity.